# Wifi adapter not found after resuming from suspended state

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

I have a dual boot machine with Win10 & Kubuntu 18.04.2 LTS installed on a Dell laptop.

I have been having an issue with the WiFi adapter (Intel Corp wireless 3160 rev83) not being found after I resume my laptop from a suspended state. This is happening on a ad-hoc basis and not every time. There is no WiFi icon in the system tray and no way to connect to the WiFi. Instead I get the red icon for a wired connection.I have tried using the below 2 commands to restart my network

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
sudo service network-manager restart
```

But this hasn't helped either.

The only way to get WiFi started is to completely shutdown my laptop and then boot it up after a few minutes. Sometimes this also needs to be done multiple times before I can get back on to the wireless network.

I don't see this as a hardware problem as booting into Win 10 has never given me this issue. The wireless adapter is always recognized and I gets connected immediately.

Following are the details of my adapter

```
 *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3160
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 83
       serial: e4:f8:9c:79:9a:ff
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-46-generic firmware=17.948900127.0 ip=192.168.1.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=I
EEE 802.11
       resources: irq:47 memory:f7100000-f7101fff
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.